# Axis WSDL2Java generation issue

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I've wrote some simple service that consists of several files (wsdl, xsd).
In xsd file I've got following definition:

```
<xs:complexType name="ServerMessage">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="type" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="info" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ServerMessage" type="tns:ServerMessage"/>
```

Then this element is referenced in wsdl file like this

```
<wsdl:message name="createItemFault">
    <wsdl:part name="createItemFault" element="tns:ServerMessage"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="Service">
    <wsdl:operation name="createItem">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:createItemRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:createItemResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault name="Fault" message="tns:createItemFault"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

And at last

```
<wsdl:binding name="ServiceBinding" type="intf:Service">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

    <wsdl:operation name="createItem">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://test.com/createItem"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="Fault">
            <soap:fault name="Fault" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

After launching WSDL2Java I receive the following code

```
public interface ServerMessage extends org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
{
```

How come ServerMessage becomes defined like this? When I've used WSDL2Java provided by Axis1 final definition in java file was like this

```
 public class ServerMessage extends org.apache.axis.AxisFault  implements java.io.Serializable
```

And after Axis2 generation resulting "item" is drastically differs, it's not even throwable. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that WSDL you should get a `CreateItemFault` (due to the `wsdl:message` name) that looks something like:

```
public class CreateItemFault extends java.lang.Exception {
    private org.example.www.service.ServerMessageDocument faultMessage;
    ...
}
```

That `ServerMessageDocument` probably looks like:

```
public interface ServerMessageDocument extends org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject {
    ...
    org.example.www.service.ServerMessage getServerMessage();

    void setServerMessage(org.example.www.service.ServerMessage serverMessage);

    org.example.www.service.ServerMessage addNewServerMessage();
    ...
}
```

And here's where we get to your `ServerMessage`:

```
public interface ServerMessage extends org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject {
    ...
}
```

The method signature should throw a `CreateItemFault`, though.

Comment: But what if I want ServerMessage type to be throwable? To use it in non-generated code as typical exception

Comment: Depends what else you want to do with it.  You could always change the names in your WSDL such that your `wsdl:message` name was `ServerMessage` (and change the `xsd:type` and `xsd:element` names to avoid naming conflicts).  The resulting object would be throwable, but would not contain the `type` and `info` attributes you defined in the schema.  Those would be present in the object that represents the type definition.